Bosch 625Wh: How to Charge Spare Battery At Home?
I have an extra Bosch 625Wh for the Bosch Cargo Line Cruise (Gen4) motor. I'd like to charge this extra battery at home while the other one is in use.
I haven't found any device I can buy to do so. Is this possible at all?
PS: It would be charged outdoors in a covered area of the patio.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Obviously it's possible; worse case you build your own charger, or try to scavenge the electronics from another bike of the same make.  If you're looking for a compatible charger from somewhere else, that would probably count as a shopping question, which isn't on-topic.  If you're looking to build your own charger, there are probably better sites to ask then this.  What exactly are you thinking of trying?

I don't know if it is possible at all; hence the very open question. whether it has to be built or purchased (non specific to any model, just if it exists) would be the next step to move on from here. thanks David!

@DavidW Not "obvious" at all. The existing battery could be "branded" to a soecific bike and charger when first connected to each, justified in order "to enhance consumer choice and protect the environment". However my general experience of Bosch tools etc. is that underlying product design is handled by hardcore engineers with a somewhat hacker mentality (use off-the-shelf components etc. where possible), even though it is later "dolled up" by marketing stylists who might have heard of things like cryptographic signatures but would be most unlikely to be able to use them properly :-)

If you have a standard Bosch Battery, you can connect the "bike" charger directly to the battery, they share the same connector.
This is mentioned in the manual (Charger BCS220 | BCS230 | BCS250):

Charging the Removed eBike Battery (see figure B)
Switch the eBike battery off and remove it from its holder on the
eBike. When doing so, read and observe the operating instructions of
the eBike battery.
Ensure the eBike battery is placed on clean surfaces only. Avoid
getting dirt, e.g. sand or soil, in the charging socket and contacts
in particular. Plug the charging connector (5) of the charger into the
char- ging socket (6) on the eBike battery.

Also, security advice:
Only charge in a well-ventilated and fire-proof location. (So, not in your living room!) Batteries can emit toxic fumes or burst into flames during charging (it has happened before...).


oh my. so simple. i don't have the battery itself to look at the connectors!!
